# Location database model for breadcrumb on a website using Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am designing a website that has a location of events as part of the information stored and displayed.

The location can be a continent, country, state/department, or a city. When an event is displayed, I would like the breadcrumb to be generated for that event.

For example if the event was in Paris:

Europe / France / Île-de-France / Paris

Each item in the breadcrumb is clickable and will bring up a list of events for that location.  It will NOT bring up events for its children regions.

I would like to make the database design compatible with Django and its models and admin functionality.

I also do not want to load all the location tables with countries, regions, and cities that are not going to be used.  I would like to add them to the database as an event is generated that needs a new location.

My original thoughts were tables for each type of location and then have four columns in the event table that are nullable.  The location type associated with the event would be determined by which location column is NOT NULL.

```
Event:
name varchar
continent_id int NULL
country_id int NULL
region_id int NULL
city_id int NULL

Continent:
id int
name varchar

Country:
id int
name varchar
countinent_id int

Region:
id int
name varchar
country_id int

Country:
id int
name varchar
region_id int
```

Another alternative would be to store the location as a varchar with all the location information in one column

```
Event:
name varchar
location varchar

example:
name: Art Festival
location: Europe:France:Île-de-France:Paris
```

Any thoughts about approach or feasibility would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well due to the overwhelming response.  I did it myself:

```
models.py

class Event(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        continent = models.ForeignKey(
        'Continent',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,)
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        'Country',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,)
    region = models.ForeignKey(
        'Region',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,)
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        'City',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,)


class Continent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(
        'Continent',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="countries",
        related_query_name="country"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        'Country',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="regions",
        related_query_name="region"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    region = models.ForeignKey(
        'Region',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="cities",
        related_query_name="city"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The setup above allows me to link locations logically.  It also lets me search for events by any locality type.